# Integrating Java and R

Tags: r, rjava, rserve, rcaller

I was looking for some third party jars to do some advanced analytical process like SQL window functions in Java,since our database mysql did not support it. With the help of google I found "R" though it is not java based but it can solve most of my cases. I have tried "RJava" and "Rcaller" interface to connect java.

For performance,scalability and long run which is the best library to connect R inside Java. Kindly advice.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that "R inside Java" means calling R from Java: JRI (part of rJava) embeds R in Java. It is the most efficient way since it is a direct JNI interface. (For a deployed example see JGR).

Another alternative is Rserve which is a client/server concept. It has the penalty of serializing data between the systems, but allows parallel connections (on unix) which is not possible with JRI since R is single-threaded so it can only be run in one thread per Java process.

RCaller is the least efficient one since it simply calls R process and thus has a cold-start problem (compared to Rserve) as well as less efficient serialization.

Comment: doesnt the single thread architecture also impose performance restrictions on Rserve as well ? May be you can have multiple connections but still the computation in R will take same amount of time in R world?

Comment: Individual R computations will take as much time in Rserve as in R (you can use threads in R for native computation, but that's a different question). The point of multiple connections is that you can run multiple computations in parallel (like running parallel R instances, just without the initial cost) which you can't do when you embed R. I mentioned it only because Java users tend to assume everything in thread-safe so they may try to create multiple `REngine` instances which works with Rserve but not JRI.